# Rsnapshot does not backup everything

Tags: ssh, rsnapshot

Now here is the issue. I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server (NUC) with a Nextcloud instance. I have raspberry pi connecting via SSH to the NUC. I have installed Rsnapshot and create cron jobs on the Raspberry Pi and it works but only with /etc/. The /ownclouddata folder is rsynced but it is empty. I suspected this is a problem of ownership (with www-data) but I quite reluctant to mess up with ownership without proper help. All those concepts are still quite blurry for me...

Any help???

This is taken from my rsnapshot.conf file on the Pi machine.

```
LOCALHOST
backup edwin@myownserver.com:/media/data/ownclouddata/ nuc/
backup edwin@myownserver.com:/etc/ nuc/
```

Comment: You should run those backup jobs a `root`. Otherwise the copied files in your backup will get the ownerships of the user which is used for the `rsync` process and you loose the ownerships of the files. This renders your backup closely to useless. If you are running the backup jobs as root already, the problem with `ownclouddata` is a different. Run the `rsnapshot` command with `-V` to see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you first have to make sure that the files in your owncloud folder on the server belong to group www-data and this group has read permissions:

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /media/data/ownclouddata
sudo chmod -R g+r /media/data/ownclouddata
```

Then add your user to the group www-data:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data edwin
```

Mind the parameters `-aG` of the usermod command: This adds the user to the group without discarding other group memberships, so this is important.